# CSS class with thicker border makes visible size of element bigger

Tags: css

I don't know if this is even possible with CSS, but I hope it is :/

- I have some div-tags, all with a certain class "abc". They all have a different length.
- Some of the divs also have a class called "highlight" which makes the border bigger. This also makes the visible lenght of the element bigger by some pixels.

I would like to change the "highlight" class to account for this somehow (which means an element with the "hightlight" class should have the same visible length as without the class.

```
.abc {
  border:solid 1px black;
}

.highlight {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: double;
}
```

I have to support IE9+ and Firefox

**BEFORE POSTING AN ANSWER PLEASE NOTE that I can NOT use the border-box model because I use the jQueryUI resizable functionality and there is a bug in combination with border-box (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8932)**

Comment: If you are talking about the *visible* lenght for jQuery you may try `outline`. This does not add up to the CSS height. As far as I know, there is **no** solution with pure CSS for the overall hight.

Comment: Seems like outline influences the "visible" length, because the outline is simply added to the element. http://jsfiddle.net/117utaew/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using inset shadows instead of borders and an additional padding to avoid overlapping:

```
.abc {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}

.highlight {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black, inset 0 0 0 2px white, inset 0 0 0 3px black;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
```